# Getting "IOTEDGE_WORKLOADURI is required." exception while debugging IoT edge solution locally

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I' following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module) to develop an IoT edge solution. But while debugging I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Environment variable IOTEDGE_WORKLOADURI is required.) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Environment variable IOTEDGE_WORKLOADURI is required.at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Edge.EdgeModuleClientFactory.CreateInternalClientFromEnvironmentAsync()
   at SampleModule.Program.Init() in D:\IoT Arch POC\EdgeSolution2\modules\SampleModule\Program.cs:line 49
```

Found one post in git hub, but that is not helpful, [this](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/584)

Comment: In that article, it asked you to install Azure IoT EdgeHub Dev Tool in order to set up your local development environment to debug, run, and test your IoT Edge solution. Did you already do that?

Comment: Please check this article in this something is useful for you:- https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-modbus/issues/48

Comment: Yes, I have installed using this command "pip install --upgrade iotedgehubdev"

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or VS Code ?

Comment: @Zied Yes, I am

Answer (score 3):

You are probably trying to run an Iot-Edge Module as a stand alone C# program? That won't work. An IoT-Edge Module must be run in the IoT-Edge or IoT-Edge simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectCapability Include="AzureIoTEdgeModule" />
</ItemGroup>
```